# Writing the contents of a struct to yml file

Tags: go, yaml

I have a struct like below

```
type config struct{
    version int
    mapping map[string]string
}
```

I would like to write the contents of the above struct to a yml file in Go.

I tried with below but no luck.

```
func writeConfig(c *config) error {
    d, err := yaml.Marshal(c)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    home, err := os.UserHomeDir()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    configpath := filepath.FromSlash(home + "/abc/config.yml")

    // Open file using READ & WRITE permission.
    file, err := os.OpenFile(configpath, os.O_RDWR, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer file.Close()

    // Write some text line-by-line to file.
    _, err = file.WriteString(string(d))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // Save file changes.
    err = file.Sync()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

**Is there is library/way to achieve this? Thank you!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This library should help you get what you need: https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml

A requirement for this is to export the members of your config struct (capital names).

Here is a short example for your struct definition:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"

    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

type config struct {
    Version int
    Mapping map[string]string
}

func main() {

    file, err := os.OpenFile("test.yml", os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE|os.O_TRUNC, 0600)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error opening/creating file: %v", err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    enc := yaml.NewEncoder(file)

    err = enc.Encode(config{
        Version: 7,
        Mapping: map[string]string{
            "key":  "value",
            "key2": "value2",
        },
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error encoding: %v", err)
    }

}
```

This will result in the following yaml file:

```
version: 7
mapping:
  key: value
  key2: value2
```

Comment: Note: for your updated example code: `yaml.Marshal` will also work, if you make the members of `config` public. Using the Encoder saves you a bit of extra code.

Comment: Cool. Thank you!